# Connecting database with C++

Tags: c++, mysql, database

Im working on some project now and I need to connect to database on VPS. On VPS I installed phpmyadmin, mysql, apache. 
I need code which connect my C++ console application with this database on VPS. I have no idea how to do it.
After connect with database I want to make login script if it changes something.

Comment: I suggest you to circle around on the web and then post here. Assuming you have a VPS hosting with apache, phpmyadmin, mysql installed. Assuming you have a c++ console app is on the same server and you want connect to DB from c++  for the further operations(fetch table).  Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424828/how-to-connect-mysql-database-using-c ?

Answer (score 0):

VPS is Virtual Private server and it is used like the normal computer. You can use the code as described in the below link for connecting the PHPmyadmin with C++ application:

[How to connect mySQL database using C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424828/how-to-connect-mysql-database-using-c)